# Object doesn't conforms to protocol

Tags: swift

```
struct IsProtocol<Pr> {
    static func implementedInObject<T>(object: T) -> Bool {
        return object is Pr
    }
}


protocol A : class {}
class B : A {}

let b = B()
println(IsProtocol<A>.implementedInObject(b))
```

Returns false. What should i do to it returns true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking conformance to protocols works only for protocols that are Objective-C compatible, i.e. marked with `@objc` directive. This is a limitation of Swift language and as much as I'd love to see it gone, we have to run with it for now.

Here comes the extract from documentation:

> You can check for protocol conformance only if your protocol is marked
>   with the @objc attribute, as seen for the HasArea protocol above. This
>   attribute indicates that the protocol should be exposed to Objective-C
>   code and is described in Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C. Even
>   if you are not interoperating with Objective-C, you need to mark your
>   protocols with the @objc attribute if you want to be able to check for
>   protocol conformance.
>
> Note also that @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes, and not
>   by structures or enumerations. If you mark your protocol as @objc in
>   order to check for conformance, you will be able to apply that
>   protocol only to class types.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

After you add `@objc`, it works properly:

```
struct IsProtocol<Pr> {
    static func implementedInObject<T>(object: T) -> Bool {
        return object is Pr
    }
}

@objc protocol A {}
class B : A {}

let b = B()
println(IsProtocol<A>.implementedInObject(b))
```

Comment: Note: adding `@objc` has an important side effects: all swift related features (generics, swift enums, etc.) cannot be used in that class or protocol. So use it wisely.